# Realizar teste condicional no Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, condição

Eu estou fazendo uma página e preciso que seja atualizada constantemente, porém, só quando o valor de uma pagina externa que chamei com a função Jquery.get() for diferente da que já está contida no arquivo, segue meu código jquery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false });
        $.get("config-stream.php?pegar=musica-atual", function(verifica){

            var musicaAtual = $("#tudo").text();        
            if(verifica != musicaAtual){
                $("#tudo").html(verifica);
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

E o respectivo HTML...

```
<div id="tudo">
    valorinicial
</div>
<p id="oi"></p>
```

Comment: Não percebi o teu problema? o que não está a funcionar?

Comment: Quando eu uso a estrutura de condicao não me retorna resultados

Comment: o que dá `console.log(musicaAtual, verifica);` antes da linha que tem o `if`?

Comment: O melhor não seria usar _stream events_ ¿